# Downvote duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, downvote-reason

If a duplicate question with hundreds of duplicates here on Stack Overflow as well as Google all over is asked again, should the question be downvoted? Or just commented (I am not yet allowed to mark as duplicate)?

Comment: Until you get enough rep. to close-vote, you can flag question and select as dupe or you can simply type in comment _Possible Duplicate of [QuestionTitle](link)_. Chances are other users will read this and if it is correct dupe, they'll CV. If you're interested, visit [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room.

Comment: "This question has not shown any research effort..." the tooltip for downvotes.

Comment: or "This question is not useful..."

Comment: Downvoted this since it seems to be a duplicate question :-)

Comment: @DavidCram ^^ I was sure somthing like this would come to this question... But i searched for things like this on SOmeta and did not find a question like this. Maybe the SOmeta-Search is not the best?... :)

Comment: @DavidCram yes, i see the linked similar question. hm... why did i not find that in the search?... no matter, i think the answer and the hints to the tooltip in the comments to this question are really good, so lets just finish thinking :)

Comment: I find that the search is not that good compared to what appears when you are typing a post and that again is not as good as when you post it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251095/let-s-improve-our-site-navigation

Comment: If the question is otherwise fine and shows effort in trying to understand/solve the problem I would still upvote it. Maybe the author's Google skills just failed him this one time. On the other hand if it's "give me teh codez" garbage I would downvote, flag as low quality and move on.

Comment: I have much more success searching for duplicates with Google than with SO's resident search.

Comment: I asked a question. Score rose to 7. Then it got marked as a dupe. Score decreased to 3. Dang

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If a question has hundreds of duplicates and could have been easily Googled, then yes, it is fair to downvote.

When commenting, make sure you are polite in tone, no matter how lazy the asker was. What I tend to comment is typically something like

> Please always remember to Google first before asking a question on Stack Overflow. A query for `insert keywords here` will turn up dozens of answers to your question.

Comment: no need for hundreds of duplicates. Even if there is only one but it can be found using only terms used by the OP (such questions are often present in the "related" section).

Comment: @njzk2 yeah. I tend to check how difficult it is to find a *good* duplicate. If I think it's reasonably easy even for a newbie, I downvote.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest even leave that comment. It implies that they didn't try googling. (though i've certainly left a few, even recently..)

Comment: @KevinB they usually haven't - and when they *have*, it's good to call them out and provoke them into a response saying so, because then they need to urgently edit their question to make it more obvious what they have already tried.

Comment: @KevinB even if they tried searching, that research isn't "shown". You could research all your life and don't find the answer, but if you don't tell others how the heck are they supposed to know?

Comment: I'm not saying they shouldn't tell us.

Comment: What i am saying is that comment can start an unconstructive argument. Better to just avoid it and cast your downvote.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on if it possible for the person that asked the question to google the solution.    Often you have to understand the problem to know what to type into google.

You then have to consider if the results on the first page of google are clearly correct answer when views by someone with limited understanding of the problem.

So if there are 101 duplicates but most of them have no useful answers I am more forgiving then if there is one clear duplicate the comes at the top on google and has a well written answer with lots of upvotes.

Comment: I agree. Also it is not always obvious which keywords to use to get the correct solution.

Comment: I've accidentally asked duplicates before now despite 30+ minutes of fruitless searching; usually because I was searching on a synonym of a term the existing question used, or had a very very slightly different circumstance meaning I was using different terms because I was approaching the problem from a different angle. Some of these duplicates get many views from people who chose the same search terms I did, who then get directed to the original. If a dupe is well written, correctly-marked duplicates containing different search terms help people find good content

Answer (score -1):

The down vote arrow has this as the hover text;

> "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not
>   useful"

Duplicates by definition *"do not show any research effort"* and *"are not useful"* because they don't add any new information to the site.

Matching 2 out of 3 criteria for the down vote explanation tells me down voting is deserved and encouraged by the wording, regardless of how many duplicate targets exist.

> It is not like you can't remove the down vote if they edit the
>   question and it is no longer a duplicate, that is actually how the site is designed to work, negative feedback is supposed to drive positive behavior outcomes.

Comment: I don't see how *"do not show any research effort"* and *"don't add any new information to the site"* are connected. The fact that the question is a dupe does not necessarily mean the poster did not put any effort, especially since you mention *"regardless of how many (or little) duplicate targets exist"*. I've seen moderators posting dupes.

Comment: Common counter-example: someone spends 30 minutes searching using terms like "clear", "empty", "delete all", "erase", etc. They find nothing. They ask a (well-written) question. 10 minutes later someone dupes it to an exact duplicate - that just happened to use the term "flush" instead (d'oh!). Their question showed effort AND is very slightly useful: SO is now a slightly better resource because people searching on "clear", "empty" and "delete all" can now find that original content more easily, via the dupe banner.