# Is it ever useful to close as duplicate if you think question deserves downvote?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, duplicate-questions

For a question that is on-topic, a duplicate, and from your point of view does not show research effort or is not useful (the kind of question discussed in [Downvote duplicate question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334361/downvote-duplicate-question)), what action should you choose (especially with gold badge):

1. Downvote and move on
2. Close as duplicate and move on
3. Downvote, close as duplicate and move on
4. Upvote and close as duplicate
5. Just move on

1 - is very non-confrontational, non-traceable and in general a safe thing to do. If a question is sufficiently low quality it will eventually just fade and get cleaned up by Roomba. No effort (short of reading the post) is wasted on your side if question is deleted soon by OP.

2 - could be considered nice by whoever voted to close, but this is a publicly traceable action. It is likely that some downvotes will be added to the post and now you are "that ***** closed my perfect question". Additionally since the question will not look good on OP's history there is a good chance it will be instantly deleted thus wasting your effort to find a duplicate.

3 - same downsides as 2, just making it even more likely to be deleted.

4 - very awkward and harder to justify voting up when you think it should be downvoted. On the plus side your effort in finding a duplicate is unlikely to be wasted as upvoted posts are not automatically removed and unlikely to be removed by OP. It also makes commenting safer even if critiquing the post.

5 - least stressful, but does not help anyone. On other hand [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)

I'm not considering "just comment" as an option since I'm not the kind of person who can express "this is asked 1000 times and answer is found by Googling the title" in a polite and friendly way.

So far I frequently do #3 (downvote + gold hammer duplicate), but I'm thinking of switching to #1 (just downvote) to get nicer interactions overall and be less concerned about wasting effort on searching for duplicates or commenting on how a duplicate is applicable. I don't really see much upside for hammering questions in such cases.

---

Example (not real) of the type of questions I'm talking about:

> "How to set text of a button. 
> I tried `var j=2* 2;` but it did not work"

Clearly no research whatsoever but you know the exact duplicate instantly. Expecting final score -2 to -5 (and hence likely deleted).

---

<sub>This question is partially sparked by what feels like frequent self-deletion by different OP of posts I hammered as duplicates, as well as a couple of unrelated events happening too close together for comfort - being called a d**k for closing a post as duplicate and reversal of serial downvotes.</sub>

Comment: I believe closing as a dupe and optionally downvoting are the correct options (it helps both the asker and potentially future visitors). But I sympathize your concern about disgruntled users. Some times I delete the auto-comment when I vote to close as a dupe, to avoid getting entangled. Lucky me with no gold on my person.

Comment: I don't think duplicates necessarily need a downvote, man times the question is asked differently and the 'original' is not suggested to the asker, many times the 'original' question is broader than the new one and the questioneer coulf improve the question by narrowing it down and editing it. I think it should be a case-to-case decision.

Comment: Imo, Yes, both. Because op bad question and poor formulation could be what  people google for. People with not enought understanding of simple issue will use wrong word. Resulting a in vague almost unclear, no mcve question. I strongly feels like you should no fear to take any of those actions. Yes there may be a better dupe target, yes user may be unsatisfied by the result. But you are not the one that wrote the poor question. I personnaly have a lot of respect for C# gold badge hammering instead of answering trivial question.

Comment: assuming the questions is bad then if you know of/can easily find a dupe then 3 is suitable, otherwise 1. if you are getting abuse from users then report this to moderators and the appropriate action should be taken, do not be 'bullied' into taking no action. Downvotes and closing are critical to maintaining quality on this site and are not a personal attack on the poster

Comment: As a gold badger wearer you are kind of obliged to do a little bit more than normal mortal, because you can. At least help to close duplicate if someone else find okeish duplicate. But as a human it's ok *sometimes* do it differently depending on your mood. Commenting only is *helpful*, just try not to write hostile comment; from high rep user it will save others time, because they could just upvote it and go instead of writing own. Option 1 is totally fine if you don't have mood to look for duplicate, but you know there is one. We are the team anyway, someone else will find it.

Comment: Are you asking which one of those you should do, or whether downvoting actually serves any purpose (in this case)? The former is arguably already essentially answered in [the question you linked to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334361/downvote-duplicate-question). The answer to the latter could potentially be derived from [the general purpose of downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/what-purpose-does-downvoting-questions-serve).

Comment: Regarding avoiding negative repercussions (and avoiding more rudeness than necessary), I've had decent luck simply avoiding engaging much in comments. I typically don't comment at all if the question is too far from salvageable or the OP doesn't seem open to feedback (those two are often related). Otherwise I may leave just one single comment asking for clarification or explaining why a question isn't a good fit for the site or is a duplicate, if I think such a comment would be constructive. My comments are usually fairly blunt, but (hopefully) not dismissive or condescending.

Comment: @Dukeling I'm trying to see if VTC as duplicate worth doing when I expect question to endup with-1 to -5 votes (i.e. greater lasting good for the site outweigh potential backlash). Sort of opposite of "should I downvote if it is duplicate". Imagine question like "How to set text of button. I tried `var j=2* 2;` but it did not work" - clearly no research whatsoever but you know exact duplicate instantly. Goldhammer will lead to direct @ comment in my inbox "**** stop downtrodding. I'm new to this and such **** make SO hostile. You ****". Downvotes will pile up and post get deleted ...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Closing is closing. Whether it's as a duplicate or for another reason, that's the best step forward to get a question deleted (which is especially relevant to a bad question). Of course it's also the best step forward if it would be a good signpost to the other question, but that's not that relevant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, if the question is bad and is an obvious duplicate (that you can lookup in seconds or have in your bookmarks), you should close it as fast as possible (and downvote if you judge it necessary)

(Optionally leave a comment explaining why it is a duplicate. That usually defuses the situation with the OP, and avoids some rare revenge downvotes)

This prevents people wasting their time trying to answer it, and avoids that answers block roomba (one often forgets that duplicates aren't roomba'ed even with negative answer scores).

Answer (score 21):

I always do either **2** or **3**. Which option I chose solely depends on the question to begin with. This has also been mentioned in the comments:

2. If the question is overall well written and one can see that at least some time was spent researching the problem, *but* not enough. Then I just close for a duplicate, leave a comment explaining *why* it's one and move on.
3. If the question is a well known problem and can be found within seconds of googling it. E.g. something along the lines of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) (which are still asked daily, *sigh*). There is no need of having 300'000 questions on Stack Overflow asking for them to help us find their `null`-reference. So downvote and close, let the roomba do its work.

Also I am not scared by the backlash that could occur:

- Serial downvoting is handled nicely by the system.
- Threats or personal attacks can easily be flagged for moderator attention.

To your last point of wasting effort to search for a duplicate:

- If you can't find a duplicate in under 2 minutes then just move on.
- If it's a question which is asked frequently still close it. And save the link into a document (I keep a small text file with links). This allows you to easily find the link again.
- Use *canned comments*. Similar to links, I have some comments saved, (There is even a userscript for this, with predefined comments), which I can just post under the question which should lead the OP to their duplicate, or at least helps them for future questions. E.g. recommend [*a lot of research*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) etc.

Comment: In my experience, canned comments on questions rarely do anything useful and may be more likely to make the asker negative towards you than a carefully crafted comments specific to the question (or no comment). Questions generally need specific feedback about what's wrong, not generic feedback. I'd honestly be dumbfounded and question everything I know about people if I see someone go in search of a duplicate in response to being told they should do more research.

Comment: Thanks of "under 2 minutes" suggestion. Could you try to cover why you think voting to close as duplicate is good for site in this case? (I.e. preventing useless duplicate answers is somewhat a reason... but -2 questions less likely to be answered anyway)

Comment: Agree with @Dukeling - canned comments are questionable... and even best attempts like idownvotedbeca.se aren't recommended (there are several discussions on it on meta)

Comment: In general I agree and do the same, unless there's no obvious dupe I remember. If I have to try more than one search to find a suitable dupe I just downvote and comment (in the lines of "This question was asked an answered before. Please do some research"). This way, I don't spend too much effort in closing a "doomed" question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov some duplicates stem from OP simply not having enough information to know they are such. With [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004) this is nearly always the case - people see that addition doesn't work correctly but can't necessarily know the underlying problem. This is a bit of an extreme case because the dupe target and actual question are usually *very different*. Still, if somebody asks a question and the dupe doesn't immediately look like it, I'd assume they didn't know how to search for it, hence why they didn't find it.

Comment: The 2 minutes is obviously a rule of thumb. Sometimes when I know the duplicate exists I end up spending quite a lot more if the search terms are tricky (typically for a case where there are many near-duplicates which are however not suitable as a duplicate).