# Do all posts deserve either an upvote or a downvote?

Tags: discussion

The upvote text reads:

> *This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear*

The downvote help text reads the opposite:

> *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*

**Are all posted questions categorically either one or the other?**

I often find myself scrolling through questions (and answers too) and feeling that a particular one doesn't really fall into *either* of these categories, and I don't feel strongly enough either way to cast a vote.

The nature of voting on Stack Overflow itself is intrinsically and intentionally subjective and opinionated (i.e., what is useful to some may be the opposite to others), so I'm not really concerned about whether people agree or disagree on a certain question. I'm more wondering about what people think about this quality gap -

Does it exist at all, or do all questions and answers always fall into one or the other category?

And tangentially, do all posts "deserve" an action in one way or the other by viewers/ voters?

There's already [plenty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253729/when-is-it-preferred-to-up-vote-a-question) [of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question) [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334361/downvote-duplicate-question) on what content deserves an upvote or downvote respectively around meta. I just found myself curious about what people make of this apparent gap, which I haven't seen referenced.

Comment: *Are all posted questions categorically either one or the other? [...] And tangentially, do all posts "deserve" an action in one way or the other by viewers/ voters?* **Of course not.** The incentive to vote or act is not a boolean (for / against) but more like a ternary (for / against / meh). With a heavy bias towards *meh*, usually.

Comment: At a minimum, I probably won't vote on a question about a technology I'm unfamiliar with that isn't *obviously* bad simply because I don't have any way of knowing how clear or useful it is.

Comment: Votes wouldn't be capped if every post needed to be voted on. You can read through hundreds of posts in a day, but only vote on 40.

Comment: Even the review queues have a "Skip" option. You're never required to act on a post.